# How to achieve this effect with React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I wonder how to do this effect with React Native. I'm aware of the side drawer component and react native GL and such, but I've no idea where to begin.

The effect is the one on the last column in this image:

[image: Coloristic Navigation effect]

Comment: what is the effect? kind of rotation in Y axis?

Comment: did you manage to get it work ?. Plz guide or post answer if you did this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transformation.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/transforms.html#proptypes

```
myStyle: {
    transform: [{ rotateY: '45deg'}]
}
```